# How to select value on a databound combobox?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that's been bound to a `DataView` that's taken a filled `DataTable`. This `DataTable` has three columns. Before the `DataView` is bound to the `ComboBox` I add another column and set some values.

```
   Dim table As DataTable = _retrieve.GetAllVersionsTable()
    table.Columns.Add("FirstRow", GetType(Boolean))

    Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
    row("ID") = -1
    row("SomeValue") = -1
    row("SomeText") = "N/A"
    row("FirstRow") = True 'Fort sorting...

    Dim view As DataView = New DataView(table)
    view.Sort = "FirstRow DESC, SomeText DESC"

    table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)

    comboBox.DataSource = view
    comboBox.ValueMember = "ID"
    comboBox.DisplayMember = "SomeText"
```

Later on, I retrieve the same data and create a new `DataTable` and bind it to a `DataGridView` in another form. From this form I set a value for the identity column from selected row in the `DataGridView`.

When I get back to the first form, with the `ComboBox`, I wish to select the `ComboBox` row that has the same value, that I set from the second form, tied to its `ValueMember` property. I thought that `SelectedValue` would work for this but it doesn't. What else can I do?

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = myIdentityValue
```

Since the rows are different I can't use `SelectedItem` either. Is there a way I can select the appropriate row without having to loop over all existing rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN:

> SelectedValue: Gets or sets the value
>   of the member property specified by
>   the ValueMember property.

So according to documentation, doing something like this should work, assuming 123 is an ID present in the combobox, because ID has been set as the ValueMember:

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = 123
```

If you can't get it to work (maybe binding with DataView doesn't work well?), then you could use SelectedIndex which always works.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that comes across this topic, has the same problems like Zolom or me. I think I found a important thing that is not documented:

You must pass the same datatype to .SelectedValue. If not the search will fail without any hint.

Let's say you fill your DataSource with with a database and have lets say integer as value-field you have to pass an integer to the SelectedIndex. If it was string you pass a string.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

That issue you can solve setting to **Nothing** the property datasource before than set the 
datasource:

```
Combobox.datasource=nothing
Combobox.DisplayMember="Data";
Combobox.ValueMember="ID";
Combobox.datasource = NewDataTable;
Combobox.SelectedValue = 4;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Combobox.text=""`. It will automatically change the selectedvalue property to your your entered text.

Comment: What entered text? Cannot understand your answer